# Nested increasing open sets

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve a question in PDE that is related to general topology. The problem I encountered can be stated as follows: (all connectivity will be path-connectivity) let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty open connected set. Can I always find a collection $\{\Omega_a\}_{a>0}$ such that:

1. For every real $a>0$, $\Omega_a$ is an open and connected set.
2. If $b>a$, then $\Omega_a \subset \Omega_b$ (proper inclusion).
3. We have $\bigcup_{a>0} \Omega_a = \Omega$.
4. For every $a > 0$, $\overline{\Omega_a} \subseteq \Omega$.

At my first attempt, I recall that if compact set $K$ is a subset of open set $V$ in a locally compact Hausdorff space, I can always find an open set $U$ with compact closure $\overline{U}$ such that $K \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq V$ so that I can just stuff all the open sets in. However, that solves only half of the problem because the $\Omega_a$'s are required to be connected. So the question can be altered as: is the same result still true if we require connectivity in addition? That is, if $K$ is connected and $V$ is connected, can I still always find a connected open set $U$ with connected compact closure $\overline{U}$ such that $K \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq V$? The $\mathbb{R}^n$ setting should help in some way but I do not know how to proceed as I do not know a lot about connectivity (nothing beyond the definition really) and I am stuck here.

Comment: Can you just pick $\Omega_a=\Omega$ for all $a$?

Comment: Sorry I forgot. The inclusion needs to be proper.

Comment: Something like $\Omega_a = \{x \in A : \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial A) > a\}$, except these may not be connected.

Comment: Perhps $\overline{\Omega_a}\subset \Omega_b$ is desired. First construct a sequence $\Omega_n$, and for $a\in(n, n+1)$, gradually increase the radius of a ball centered at a point $x\in\overline{\Omega_{n}}\setminus \Omega_n$. To construct $\Omega_n$, use GEdgar's idea, and if we have a disconnected domain, there can be at most countably many connected components, and for each pair of them, connect them with a path, add some balls along the path to the domain, using the images of the path is compact, there should be a way to justify this, but I haven't worked out the details.